# load time not displaying where it should be

Tags: php, mysql

I don't understand this issue, i am displaying mysql data and then after it is the page load timer. Now i have placed the timer function after the sql display and things are loading in reverse. The Penguins generate the time at the end.
[image]

```
    <?php

// Time Record Start
$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$time = $time[1] + $time[0];
$start = $time;

require_once("models/config.php");
if (!securePage($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])){die();}
require_once("models/header.php");

echo "
<body>
<div align='center'>";
echo "
</div>
<div id='wrapper'>
<div id='top'><div id='logo'></div></div>
<div id='content'>
<h1>site</h1>
<h2>Internal Contact Management</h2>
<div id='left-nav'>";

include("left-nav.php");

echo "
</div>
<div id='main'>
Hey, $loggedInUser->displayname.</br></br>
<div align='center'><a href='admin_contacts_add.php'>Add</a></div>";

include('conn.php');
$query1=mysql_query("select * from contacts ORDER BY `contacts`.`name` ASC");
echo "<table align='center' width='60%'>    
        <tr>
            <td><b>Name</b></td>
            <td><b>Phone</b></td>
            <td><b>Ext</b></td>
            <td><b>Mobile</b></td>
            <td><b>Edit</b></td>
            <td><b>Delete</b></td>";
while($query2=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{
echo "<tr><td>".$query2['name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$query2['phone']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$query2['ext']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$query2['mobile']."</td>";
echo "<td><a href='admin_contacts_edit.php?id=".$query2['id']."'>Edit</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='admin_contacts_delete.php?id=".$query2['id']."'>Delete</a></td><tr>";
}";
</ol>
</table>
</div>";
// Time Calculate and generate
$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$time = $time[1] + $time[0];
$finish = $time;
$total_time = round(($finish - $start), 4);
$page = 'admin_contacts_view.php';
echo '</br>';
echo '<div align="center">Penguins generated this in '.$total_time.' seconds.</div>';
// Insert Time Data
$sql = "INSERT INTO preformance (page, time) VALUES('$page', '$total_time')";
$insert = $mysqli->query($sql);
echo "
<div id='bottom'></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>";

?>
```

Comment: That's probably because the html is invalid, you are not closing the rows of the table and there is a `</ol>` where there shouldn't be for example.

Comment: lol im such a noob, found some errors but still not aligning. let me read it again, mite be a simple formatting error.

Answer (score 0):

I just did not look hard enough to fix it, the main issue was the between the closing tr and the closing table and adding another echo "

```
while($query2=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{
    echo "<tr>
            <td>".$query2['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$query2['phone']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$query2['ext']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$query2['mobile']."</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='admin_contacts_edit.php?id=".$query2['id']."'>Edit</a></td>";
    echo "<td><a href='admin_contacts_delete.php?id=".$query2['id']."'>Delete</a></td>
        </tr>";
}
echo "
</table>
```